# Eclipse doesn't show warnings for maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have created a new maven project on Eclipse ignoring the archetype (using create simple project tick-box). Eclipse automatically created the src directory with main and test, pom.xml etc. However, it is not able to recongise java.

What I mean by that is after creating java classes (which was not straightforward like creating classes and interfaces for Java project). and by deliberately typing wrong java syntax in the source file, it doesn't produce any warnings.

Why is that? and why is it when I create an iterface, I can't find it in the interface selection box for implementing it?

Comment: Have you refreshed the the project (shortcut: alt + F5)? Sometimes Eclipse and Maven behave strange, refresh or restart eclipse may help.

Comment: I did, but same problem!

Comment: If a facet of your project is not "Java", it seems obvious that Eclipse does not try to compile it. Your project has a small "J" on it's directory icon in the Eclipse project explorer ?

Comment: Thanks, its working now, the problem was that the project did not have a facet.